# Sorting using custom comparator function in python

Tags: python, sorting, comparator, custom-sort

i have a list L = [['92', '022'], ['77', '13'], ['82', '12']]

want to sort on second element as key : ['022','13','12']

having to custom functions for numerically sort and lexicographically sort.
but not getting the desired output...

for numerically sort output like : [['82', '12'],['77', '13'],['92', '022']]

for lexicographically sort output like : [['92', '022'],['82', '12'], ['77', '13']]

```
from functools import cmp_to_key

L = [['92', '022'], ['77', '13'], ['82', '12']]
key=2

def compare_num(item1,item2):
   return (int(item1[key-1]) > int(item2[key-1]))

def compare_lex(item1,item2):
   return item1[key-1]<item2[key-1]

print(sorted(l, key=cmp_to_key(compare_num)))
print(sorted(l, key=cmp_to_key(compare_lex)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this - it should work:

```
L = [['92', '022'], ['77', '13'], ['82', '12']]

#Numerically sorted:
sorted(L, key = lambda x: x[-1])
[['92', '022'], ['82', '12'], ['77', '13']]

#Lexicographically sorted:
sorted(L, key = lambda x: int(x[-1]))
[['82', '12'], ['77', '13'], ['92', '022']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making it complex. `key` argument can take a custom function.

```
l = [['92', '022'], ['77', '13'], ['82', '12']]
key = 2

def compare_num(item1):
   return int(item1[key-1])

def compare_lex(item1):
   return item1[key-1]

print(sorted(l, key=compare_num))
print(sorted(l, key=compare_lex))
```